# Installation of ies4linux in ubuntu 10.10

Tags: wine, ubuntu-10.10

I was trying to install Internet Explorer on Ubuntu 10.10 but I was not successful.

I installed Wine 1.2 and Wine-Doors and, using Wine tricks, I could run Internet Explorer, but it is crashing whenever I try to open a new tab.

Please help me out and let me know the stable version of IE for use on Ubuntu 10.10 is.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Wine AppDB](http://appdb.winehq.org/), IE 7 is the most recent version of Internet Explorer that runs in Wine.

You can find its page [here](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=4195).

---

Also, when installing, it is recommended that you use [winetricks](http://wiki.winehq.org/winetricks), as it downloads and configures everything for you.